# Imaginary complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-analysis

Let $z=x+iy$ and $v=2xy$, show that $v=Im[z^2]$ and find a harmonic conjugate of $v$ on domain $D$. Also find the largest domain $D$ on which $v$ is harmonic.

Comment: I don't know how to start showing v=Im[z^2] and I don't truly understand the meaning of a harmonic conjugate.

Comment: To show $v=\operatorname{im}(z^2)$, start by squaring $z$ and then take its imaginary part.

Comment: @xfitpi: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to formats questions/answers using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, thanks I will do that!

Comment: to find the harmonic conjugate use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. The largest domain question is rather obvious

Answer (score 1):

$z^2=(x+iy)^2=x^2+2xiy+i^2y^2=...$ continue then conclude with its imaginary part.

The holomorphic function would be $z\mapsto z^2$, it is defined on all $\Bbb C$. The harmonic conjugate would be then $u:=z\mapsto Re[z^2]$. Verify that these satisfy the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).